# Android sticky-footer: Align footer view to table, until it reaches screen size, then become fixed.at the bottom

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout, sticky-footer

This should be similar to an iOS tableview footer, also seen in various websites (sticky-footer).

I want to achieve the following:

[image: diagram]

**A** is a `RecyclerView` with variable number of rows.

When **A** is smaller than screen (or parent) size, **B** (footer) should be placed bellow the last row.

When **A** + **B** are bigger than screen size, then **B** becomes fixed at the bottom and **A** content is scrollable.

We are currently performing this with `onMeasure` functions that calculate all components heights in order to resize A accordingly.

I was wondering if there is an easier way to do it, maybe with `ConstraintLayout`.

Answer (score 5):

Put `A` and `B` in a vertical packed chain with a bias of `0` to align it to the top. You also need to set `app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"` for the `RecyclerView` so that its constraints are taken into account when it gets too big to fit them (parent's height remains `match_parent` in this case):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/A"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/B" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/B"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Footer"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/A"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The above solution does not seem to work on `Constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta2`, looks like a bug introduced in that version. Works on `2.0.0-beta1` and `1.1.3`.

Another way would be to set parent's height to `wrap_content` and then you can use the default chainstyle and remove the bias:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/A"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/B" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/B"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Footer"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/A"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This solution works on all versions.

Comment: @Pawel Laskowski quick question. I have tried this and was not working if the item of the recyclerView uses a constraint layout to wrap content itself, if the item uses a fix height  with constraintLayout or a linearLayout then it works fine. Version 1.1.3 and 2.0.0-beta 6

Is it a bug on constraint layout?

Comment: @Javier Vieira I don't think it's a bug - without looking at your item's layout my guess would be that you are missing a bottom constraint for the last item (on the bottom). Try adding `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"` to it

Comment: @Pawel Laskowski thanks a lot :D
It was not that, but you made me review it, I had a textview in the item with android:layout_width="0dp", and when it was multiple lines, then it was pushing all the way down the last item, making it also  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 with  app:layout_constrainedWidth="true" made the trick :D

Answer (score 1):

Just try ConstraintLayout, this should very well be possible, just fix Bs height and constrain it to the bottom and A and turn the bias up to top.